# Using a single sequence table in Postgres

Tags: mysql, postgresql, jpa

I have an Eclipse Link JPA application that use Postgres as the DBMS.  By default, when the application deploys it builds s Sequence table that holds a single row counter.  Keys for all tables are generated from this single table.  The alternative is that multiple sequences are used - one for each table.  This will result in a structure very much like MySQL's auto-increment feature.  Is there a determinant of the most appropriate approach or is it very much a matter of style?  A single sequence seems to be cleaner and simplier.

Comment: Can't you tell EclipseLink to use native Postgres sequences? They will be *much* faster than anything a client library can implement. Or make use of Postgres' `serial' type? (which is similar to MySQL's auto_increment).

Comment: One sequence per table is *much* more in line with how things are usually done in PostgreSQL (with the `SERIAL` pseudo-type). In the end it doesn't matter much unless you're burning though a lot of IDs, though with a single sequence you'll need biginteger (long) keys sooner than with per-table sequences.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name If it's behaving anything like Hibernate it might well be using native Pg sequences, but just creating a single one. Hibernate likes to create a `hibernate_sequence` with a default increment of 50, grab IDs from that into a local pool, and hand them out to requestors in-process.

Comment: Using Postgres sequences is possible (I think) however the application is designed to plug into MySQL and others as an alternative - so the code has a generic solution.

Comment: "*so the code has a generic solution*" - I thought that's what the obfuscation layer (aka ORM) is supposed to handle for you?

Comment: Actually, I wondered what happens with this configuration when you run out of keys?  :)

Comment: Apologies - I was not clear.  Eclipse link is used and that is where the configuration is.  Eclipse link seems to default to a single "sequence" table.  I don’t believe that there is anything in Spring data that does this - but I stand to be corrected